# Understanding generics and reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I need some help with generics and reflection in java.

What I try to achieve is a factory class that based on a class `MyClass` returns another class `MyClassStore` that implements an interface `Store<MyClass>`.

How can I make sure that the right type of store is returned with reflection.

See sample code:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Store<MyClass> store = Factory.getFactory(MyClass.class);
        MyClass myClass = store.get();
        System.out.println(myClass.getId());

    }

}

public class Factory {

    public static <T> Store<T> getFactory(Class<T> type) {

        Store<T> store = null;
        // TODO: How to implement this
        return store;

    }

}

public class MyClassStore implements Store<MyClass>{

    public MyClass get() {
        return new MyClass("1000");
    }

}

public interface Store<T> {

    public T get();

}

public class MyClass {

    private String id;

    public MyClass(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

I have tried different ways but can't get it to work the way I want. This is the implementation I have tried. But is there a better way?

```
    public static <T> Store<T> getFactory(Class<T> type) {

        Store<T> store = null;

        if (type == MyClass.class) {
            store = (Store<T>) new MyClassStore();
        }

        return store;

    }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like it, though it looks like what you want is `type == MyClass.class` rather than `MyClassStore.class`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, you're right, I updated the example. But there has to better way and use reflection?

Answer (score 0):

Just taking the problem as stated, the best solution I can come up with is to have a `static final Map<Class, Class>` in the `Factory` that maps (in this example) from `MyClass.class` to `MyClassStore.class`, use it to look up which class to instantiate, and call `newInstance()` on the `Class` retrieved from the map.

Taking a bit more liberty with your design, you could replace `MyClassStore` with a more general generic class that takes a `Class<T>` parameter, stores it locally, and implements `get()` with a call to `newInstance()` on the stored `Class`. `getFactory()` could then simply make a generic store regardless and pass the `Class` object on.

However, this type of code strikes me as unlikely to be a good solution to whatever your real problem is. Why does `MyClassStore` need to create new `MyClass` objects? Why does the internal logic of any implementation of `Store` need to care about what type `T` actually is? That latter question in particular is usually a strong indicator of poor design in my opinion.